# $f$ is concave, $g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is decreasing, prove that $g\circ f$ is convex

Tags: general-topology, locally-convex-spaces

Please prove that
if the function $f$ is concave and $g:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is decreasing, 
then $g\circ f$ is convex.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Let us know what you have tried and where you are stuck so that we can hint you towards a solution. Also, please use $\LaTeX$ formatting.

Answer (score 2):

Take $s,t \geq 0$ with $s + t = 1$. Take $x,y \in \Bbb R$. By definition of concavity,
$$
f(sx + ty) \geq sf(x) + tf(y)
$$
By definition of a decreasing function, this means that
$$
g(f(sx + ty)) \leq g(sf(x) + tf(y))
$$
At this point, we would need an additional statement like "$g$ is convex"  to state that
$$
g(sf(x) + tf(y)) \leq s\,g(f(x)) + t\,g(f(y))
$$
however, outside of that, I don't believe the statement holds.

Answer (score 0):

The identity function $f(x) = x$ is concave, so the result implies every decreasing function is convex.  Doubtful...